# se puede hacer un media query a un useState en React?

Tags: reactjs, condiciones, programación-móvil, mediaqueries, usestate

Estoy utilizando la libreria react-animate-height para hacer un accordion y necesito hacer una condicion donde especifique para desktop que quede abierto "useCollapsible('auto')" y para mobile que quede cerrado "useCollapsible(0)" no se como hacer la condicion q cambie el estado inicial

```
const CategoriesList = ({ intl, categoriesList, selectedFilter, onSelectCategory }) => {
  const [componentHeight, setComponentHeight] = useCollapsible('auto'); //acordion abierto

  return (
    <div className="filter-services">
      <ContainerHeader
        title={intl.formatMessage(messages.sortBy)}
        onClick={setComponentHeight}
        opened={componentHeight !== 0}
        hasChevron
      />
      <AnimateHeight duration={300} height={componentHeight}>
        <div className="content-items">
          {categoriesList.map(({ id, name }) => {
            const activeFilter = selectedFilter === id;

            return (
              <Fragment key={id}>
                <div className="filter-services-row" onClick={() => onSelectCategory(id)}>
                  <div className="filter-services-flex">
                    <div className={cn('filter-services-sort', { active: activeFilter })}>
                      {name}
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  {activeFilter && <div className="filter-services-sort-active" />}
                </div>
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </AnimateHeight>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Que yo sepa no es posible usar CSS para llamar funciones de javascript. Debe haber alguna alternativa ¿Cuál sería la condición? Tal vez esto ayude https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862446/13419694

Comment: ¿Qué sería para ti la diferencia entre mobile y desktop? Hablas de `media query`, por lo cual supongo que te vas a basar en el ancho de pantalla (lo usual en `media query`). Si es eso, podrías usar la propiedad `window.innerWidth` para determinar si la pantalla tiene el tamaño adecuado. Supongamos que para ti, *mobile* es todo aquello con ancho menor a 900px, entonces una opción sería: `useCollapsible(window.innerWidth < 900 ? 0 : 'auto');`

Comment: Aunque, como se enlaza en el otro comentario, lo ideal es usar tu propio `hook`. De esta forma el código se hace más extensible y no te tienes que preocupar por la lógica de los cambios de tamaño de pantalla, dentro de tu componente, ya que de ello se encargará el `hook`.